# R: error, the condition has length>1 in if statement

Tags: r

I fairly new to R and I'm trying to wrap my head around this error. I've already consulted other questions regarding it and all of them imply that the error is thrown when there is a vector/list in the condition of an if statement, but that's not my case. I have only one condition:

```
if (dataset$scda == "I"){
    a=1
}else if (dataset$scda == "A"){
    a=2
}else{
    a=0
}
```

And it throws the error

```
Error in if (dataset$scda == "I") { : 
  the condition has length > 1
Execution halted
```

I've tried to find out if the problem is caused by a vector in the condition, however, the output of

`print(class(dataset$scda))`
is
`[1] "character"`

So the standard answer I've found so far (e.g. "you have a vector in the condition") doesn't apply.

Comment: It does apply :) A vector is when `length(...)` is > 1 (as error states), a scalar is when `length(...)` is 1.  In your case check `length(dataset$scda)` . `if` is used with scalars and `ifelse` with vectors.

Comment: you are right! i don't know why it didn't cross my mind to check the length, I just assumed it was a character, silly me. Thank you!